# How to get an Enumerator[T] from List[T] when using Play 2 Iteratees

Tags: functional-programming, playframework-2.0, enumerator, loops

I am quite new to Play 2 and am trying Iteratees.

Q1. How can I get an `Enumerator[Person]` from `List[Person]`?

Q2. When I try to pass an `Enumerator(Option[String])` to `Ok.stream` I get an error on console stating that

> Cannot write an instance of Option[String] to HTTP response. Try to define a  Writeable[Option[String]]

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can define a Writeable for custom types to HTTP response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A1. You can use `Enumerator#enumerate` to run Iteratee for each `Person`

```
val persons: List[Person] = List(person0, person1)  
Enumerator.enumerate(persons) |>>> Iteratee.foreach(println _)
```

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.0/framework/src/iteratees/src/test/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/EnumeratorsSpec.scala#L74-L83

A2. Instead of defining `Writeable[Option[String]]`, extract `String` from `Option[String]`

```
Ok.stream(
   Enumerator(Option("kiki"), Option("foo"), Option("bar")).map(_.get) >>> Enumerator.eof
)
```